# How to disable HT in a Intel Atom D425?

Tags: bios, hyper-threading, intel-atom

I can't find in the BIOS the option to disable HT.
Is this a BIOS problem or the processor itself doesn't support running as a single core?

Comment: What motherboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, disabling HTT is something that the BIOS should care about, so it all depends on your specific BIOS, and that depends on what the manufacturer wanted to include or not.

I'd just add that since this is a single core cpu, you could just boot your operating system with SMP disabled and you should, more or less, get the same effect. As an example, in linux you would boot with the `nosmp` kernel command line option. - I wouldn't have recommended that on a dual core cpu (quad thread with HTT enabled) since you would loose the second core.

Besides this, are you sure you want to disable hyperthreading? Seems like recent HTT implementations by Intel (ie, Atom, Core i5/i7) are actually good ones and, also adding recent operating system evolutions, there isn't nearly anything to gain disabling them. On the old pentium-4 with non heavily multithreading optimized operating systems it was a different story, and some specific workloads would actually run faster with htt disabled.

Comment: [How to disable SMP in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/199108/how-to-disable-smp-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Your processor actually is a single core, with two threads.  HT is just something that Intel developed in the name of "performance".  I believe that perhaps the manufacturer did not include that option in their BIOS for one reason or another.