# How to disable SMP in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, smp

[Somebody](https://superuser.com/questions/199085/how-to-disable-ht-in-a-intel-atom-d425/199095#199095) told me to disable the SMP to reduce the number of cores to 1. How can I do that in Windows 7?

Comment: Why do you need to do that ?

Comment: @Sathya I can't disable HT in the BIOS, and HT is causing me problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work, but worth a shot. Launch `msconfig` ( <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> type `msconfig` )

Head over to `Boot` -> `Advanced options` -> `Number of processors` -> `1`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the Sathya's solution made my computer unstable (unreasonable CPU usage on 100% without doing anything).

With core parking you can also "disable" cores. By setting `performance core parking max cores` you set how many cores will be parked all the time. [Link](https://kastoestoramadus.github.io/os/2016/10/30/windows-core-parking-saving.html)